# databricks udf broadcast dictionary value returns list of dictionaries; can't access values from dictionaries in that list

Tags: python, dictionary, user-defined-functions, databricks

The code below was built based on [udf dictionary broadcast](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/udf-dict-broadcast/) blog posting.  In the code below the broadcast dictionary should return a lists of dictionaries ie Expected return from broadcast dictionary {'key':[{'key':'value','key2':'value'},{'key':'value','key2':'value'}]

When I try to access any key from a dictionary in the list no value is returned.  I know this because I get an error "local variable 'tmp' referenced before assignment".  This variables should contain a calculated value resulting from operations defined in each dictionary in the list.  Can anyone tell me why or how to debug this or why the dictionary keys are not returning values ?  I added print statements in the code that returns the broadcast key but it never appears in the ouput or driver logs.

broadcast dictionary

```
calc dict {'name': 'Lvl1_Name_Score', 'operations': [{'operator': 'multi', 'value': 1.5}, {'operator': 'div', 'value': 1}]}
```

```
def apply_weights_a(calc_broadcasted,key): 
    def apply_weights(col_name):
        calc_operations = calc_broadcasted.value.get(key)
        results = 0
        print(f'calc_operations {calc_operations}')
        for op in calc_operations:
            print(f'op {op}')
            # for i,op in enumerate(calc['dependencies']
            if op['operator'] == 'div': tmp = col_name / float(op['value'])
            elif op['operator'] == 'multi': tmp = col_name * float(op['value'])
            elif op['operator'] == 'sub':tmp = col_name - float(op['value'])
            elif op['operator'] == 'add': tmp = col_name + float(op['value'])
        # sdf = sdf['tmp'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 0 else x)
        results = results + tmp
        return results
    return udf(apply_weights)


def multi_apply_weights(col_names,weights): 
    def inner(sdf):
        for col_name in col_names:
            #print(f"weights {weights}")
            size = len(col_name)  #get col_name without _c
            calc = [mylist for mylist in weights if mylist['name'] == col_name[:size-2] ]
            #print(f"calc {calc}")
            calc_dict = calc[0]
            #print(f"calc dict {calc[0]}")
            b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(calc_dict)
            sdf = sdf.withColumn(
                col_name,
                apply_weights_a(b,'operations')(col_name)
            )
        return sdf
    return inner

sdf = multi_apply_weights(weight_list,config['algorithmScores'])(sdf)
```

This spark code is the result of converting this pandas function which performs 1 to multiple different calculations on a set of columns...

```
def apply_weights(df, weights):
    for calc in weights:
        col = calc['name']
        for op in calc['operations']:
            if op['operator'] == 'div':
                df[col + '_w'] = df[col]/float(op['value'])
            elif op['operator'] == 'multi':
                df[col+ '_w'] = df[col]*float(op['value'])
            elif op['operator'] == 'sub':
                df[col+ '_w'] = df[col]-float(op['value'])
            elif op['operator'] == 'add':
                df[col+ '_w'] = df[col]+float(op['value'])
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: 0 if x < 0 else x)

    return df
```

Comment: You might have better luck if you make your code more minimalistic? It's a lot of code to get into. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to run the original python code by making a minor change.  This worked on 3 of my 4 functions.  When using this approach on my last function it caused my cluster to crash with the error ''The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached'.  I have opened a ticket with microsoft to get addtional help with this.

```
def apply_weights(kdf, weights) -> ks.DataFrame[zip(kdf.dtypes, kdf.columns)]:
```

I also resolved the issue with broadcasting the dictionary by adding a key before broadcasting.  I changed the broadcast to

```
brdcst = dict({"rules":newcolrules})
b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(brdcst) 

calcs = b.value.get('rules') #test broadcasted dictionary
print(f"calcs : {calcs}") #test broadcasted dictionary
```